# how to stop a batch script from renaming itself?

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make a script that renames all files except itself in the folder the script is located in, how can i prevent this?

I tried excluding all .bat files but this doesnt seem to work.

```
set /P name="New name: "
set /A int= 1

for %%I in ("%selectedDirectory%\*") do (
    echo %%I
    if not %%I == *.bat (
        echo %%I 
        ren %%I %name%!int!.* 
        set /A int += 1 
    )
)
```

Comment: check out https://superuser.com/questions/709651/how-to-perform-wildcard-string-comparison-in-batch-file

Comment: What happens if you change `if not %%I == *.bat (` to `If Not "%%~nxI"=="%~nx0" (`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```bat
@echo off
set /P name="New name: "
set /A int=1

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "selectedDirectory=%userprofile%\Desktop"
for %%I in ("%selectedDirectory%\*") do (
    If Not "%%~nxI"=="%~nx0" (
        echo %%I 
        echo ren %%I %name%_%%~nI_!int!%%~xI & pause
        set /A int+=1 
    )
) 
pause & exit
```

So check it and if the output is correct you can get rid from the `echo` before the `ren` command